# Why my digital signage solution with Raspberry doesn't correctly works?

Tags: javascript, html, css, raspberry-pi, kiosk-mode

I am trying to achieve a **Digital Signage** using Raspbian OS on my Raspberry. I set my r-pi to open in kiosk mode chromium browser and to shows a slideshow od ads and scrolling news within my web application. 
I created the ads slideshow using [jquery image slideshow](http://responsiveslides.com/) and scrolling news with **marquee** html tag.
The result is jerkily scrolling news. 
I think the problem is due to the couple "jquery-marquee" because if I run only jquery or only marquee it works!
Can you give me some ideas?
I thought to only use CSS3 to realize scrolling news and scrolling ads

**UPDATE:** You can see my work [here](http://thebit.altervista.org/slideshow/)
From normal browser it works. From chromium v.22 on raspbian-raspberry it is a disaster. 
I have already choosen little images  (not bigegr than 200kb) but the problem remains.
I utilised [jquery image slideshow](http://responsiveslides.com/) and [jquery.marquee](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin)

I hope you can help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The marquee tag is crap. Use a Javascript-based solution.

Comment: Please can you show us some code? As it is any answer would (necessarily) be based on guess work - please provide at least HTML and CSS. Does the site work well on other hardware/other browsers? Please note that the marquee element is non-standard and use is now strongly discouraged - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: @pwdst I updated my question. Now you can see my "working" solution

Comment: Not `marquee`!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: it's not a marquee! It is obtained by jQuery

Comment: @War10ck can you give me an example with doen't uses marquee? Because I though I would not be using marquee

Comment: Remember a raspberry pi does not have that much horsepower, although the GPU is fairly decent (for its price).  Have you found a image switcher that actually works with the raspberry pi?  My guess is one that mostly uses CSS 3 transforms and animation might work better, but that would have to be determined.

Comment: Actually... it seems to use my suggestions on a desktop browser.  (I just reread your question and you seem to imply that, oops!) Those are some big images.  I'm not terribly surprised there might be some issue. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I just read a bit from http://blogs.wcode.org/2013/09/howto-boot-your-raspberry-pi-into-a-fullscreen-browser-kiosk/ and noticed:

> Optional bonus Step 4: Accelerated X11 Server
>
> Currently (Sep 2013), the default X11 server isn’t exactly optimised
>   for the Raspberry Pi; however, work is afoot and you can install a
>   work-in-progress version fairly easily. This has worked for us and has
>   been nice and stable. YMMV.
>
> UPDATE: Comments have suggested possible problems with newer Rasbian
>   releases. We’ve not verified this either way. You don’t need to
>   install this, everything will work just fine without it; at the time,
>   we were trying to squeeze every last ounce of performance from the Pi,
>   so it seemed pertinent to install this patch.

The blog mentions an accellerated X11 server

- https://github.com/simonjhall/fbdev_exa/ , or in particular
- https://github.com/simonjhall/fbdev_exa/tree/master/releases/20130401

Maybe following the instructions on that blog link might help.

Comment: do you think I can solve this issue using CSS3 and/or following your suggestion to patch x11 server?

Comment: I founded this interesting [tutorial](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/): I tested it with qemu and is seems works. Do you think that can be a solution for my issue?